# Unicode convert to Utf 8

Tags: unicode, utf-8, bit

I want convert U+0780 to UTF-8.

Table:

```
U+00000000 - U+0000007F     0xxxxxxx

U+00000080 - U+000007FF     110xxxxx 10xxxxxx

U+00000800 - U+0000FFFF     1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx

U+00010000 - U+001FFFFF     11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

Convert 0780 from hex to binary.

```
00000111 10000000
```

I choose second line of table

```
110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

How I fill bits to `00000111 10000000` to template `110xxxxx 10xxxxxx`

Comment: Any particular language in mind?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Examples explains this with details and colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template is `110xxxxx 10xxxxxx`, so there are 11 bits available.

Take the 11 used bits of the character: `111 10000000`, put them in the template in that order, left to right, five leftmost bits `11110` for the first byte and the remaining six bits `000000` for the second byte.

You get: `11011110 10000000`.